# Windows App (WPF) vs Web App (run on localhost) for POS Application

Tags: winforms, webforms

**Windows App (WPF) vs Web App (HTML5 run on localhost) for POS (Point of Sale) Application.**

Which one should I choose, and the pros and cons of each one is what.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question at this point is very open ended. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/tour for help asking more narrowed questions.

Comment: That depends on a bunch of factors. Which technology do you know better? I'd go with WPF for ease of development and maintainability, javascript sucks. But that, again, depends on your skills